# How to Confirm Vibrate Motor is Dead on iPhone 5S iOS 7.1

Tags: ios, iphone, vibrate

My iPhone 5S running iOS 7.1 will not vibrate at all.  I've run through numerous setting suggestions and combos (hardware and software switches), but it won't vibrate for e-mail, for texts, nor will it vibrate when you select a new vibration tone (IIRC, that usually demos the vibration when you do that).  It's not the 'do not disturb' on the control center either.

To me, this sounds like the motor is broken.  Is there a means of verifying that the motor is the problem, other than going to the Apple Store?

Comment: Flip the Ring/Silent switch on the side of iPhone.

Comment: Cycling that switch does not vibrate, but it does on another phone which operates correctly.  Thanks.

Comment: Reinstall the OS.

Comment: How can I do that once the software is up to date?  It is at 7.1.2 which is current.  How can I force it?

Comment: Motor was broken - fixed at Apple Store under warranty.